# frequency-domain vector potential A at a point P

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, vectors, classical-electrodynamics

I am new to this website but I hope someone can help me figure out or understand how to solve a 'basic' (yet I am struggling) line integral.

The *frequency-domain vector potential* **A** at the point P(0 ,0, z) due to a circular current filament carrying a current (located in ρ = a and z=0)  **i(t)= IocosΦcosωt** in the *aΦ* direction (Io is a constant)

$$A = \int_l \frac{uI(t)e^{-jkR}}{4\pi R} dl $$

I then solve it as usual: R = -ρ (aρ) + z(az) and dl = adΦ(aΦ) and setting ρ = a.  However if I integrate I(t)dl over Φ (0 to 2pi) I get 0 (integral of cosΦ).

But this seems wrong.

Any tip would be very much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

---

/\ **EDIT**

What if I transform *dl* to carthesian coordinates and get dl = adΦ(aΦ) = a(-sinΦ **x** + cosΦ **y**) dΦ. This should solve it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I understand, should I detail my question to a particular aspect then? "We expect you to narrow down the problem to the particular concept that's giving you trouble and ask about that specifically". I'll edit my question.

Comment: I have just added an answer, I believe the problem is solved but I wouldn't like to induce others to a mistake should I set it as solved?